# Thymeleaf не отображает ошибки

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Thymeleaf не отображает ошибки

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/call/add}" th:object="${call}" method="post">
    <label for="Destination">Исходящий</label>
    <input type="checkbox" th:checked="*{Destination}" id="Destination" placeholder="Направление" />
    <label for="Number">Номер</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{Number}" id="Number" placeholder="Номер" />
    <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('Number')}" th:errors="*{Number}">номер не должен быть пустым</p>
    <label for="Caller">Абонент</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{Caller}" id="Caller" placeholder="Абонент" />
    <label for="Operator">Оператор</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{Operator}" id="Operator" placeholder="Оператор" />
    <label for="CallDate">Дата звонка</label>
    <input type="date" th:field="*{CallDate}" id="CallDate" placeholder="Дата звонка" />
    <label for="Comment">Комментарий</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{Comment}" id="Comment" placeholder="Комментарий" />
    <input type="submit" value="Добавить">
    <ul>
        <li th:each="e : ${#fields.detailedErrors()}" th:class="${e.global}? globalerr : fielderr">
            <span th:text="${e.global}? '*' : ${e.fieldName}">The field name</span> |
            <span th:text="${e.message}">The error message</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Контроллер

```
@PostMapping(value = "/add")
public String addCall(@Valid PhoneCall call, BindingResult result, Model model){
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("call", call);
        return "add-call";
    }
    phoneCallService.save(call);
    model.addAttribute("calls", phoneCallService.findAll());
    return "index";
}
```

аннотированное поле

```
@NotBlank(message = "Номер не должен быть пустым")
    private String Number;
```

Answer (score 0):

Все дело в именовании.

```
model.addAttribute("phoneCall", call);

<form action="#" th:action="@{/call/add}" th:object="${phoneCall}" method="post">
```